# How to attach a file with capybara?

Tags: ruby, file, rspec, tdd, capybara

In my view, I use this:

```
<%= file_field_tag 'my_file' %>
# html will be:
<input type="file" name="my_file" id="my_file" />
```

In my spec file, I tried:

```
it 'file test' do
  attach_file 'my_file', 'my/file/path'
end
```

But it said:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
  Unable to find file field "my_file"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
  it 'file test' do
    post :my_file, avatar: fixture_file_upload('my/file/path', 'image/jpg')
    response.should be_success
  end
```

Comment: Thank you. What I want to do is that `attach_file`, then `click_button`, finally want to expect page have a special content on the next page. I am doing a feature test: `type: :feature`, so I can't use `post`.